# anaconda navigator is not opening on my windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

i have installed anaconda but it is not opening . whenever i open anaconda prompt it always shows error message " 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.Spyder ide is also not opening

Comment: Did you add the path where `conda` is to your `PATH` variable?

Comment: Kindly consider adding os information, from the look of it it looks like you are using windows. if that is the case can you open anaconda navigator ?? if so try running spyder or jupyter notebook from there

Comment: where should i add the path even anaconda prompt is showing the error msg whenever i type anything@HSK

Comment: where should i add os information???anaconda navigator is also not opening